# How to forcibly disconnect a application listening on a port

Tags: windows, port, application

I have an app that doesn't properly stop listening on a port.

How do I force it to stop so I can open the application again/use that port again?

Comment: Appears as though bobber205 is asking for a windows answer based on his tag "windows".  @bobber205 - care to confirm this?

Comment: @Patrick R: bobber205 did not tag it windows; thepocketwade did. You can confirm that it is windows by looking at his comment to Stephen Thompson's answer.

Comment: @Kevin M - I was attempting to gentle nudge bobber205 to be more clear when he created questions.  Especially since the first answer he received was about unix (where I had clearly seen that he had left a comment that he needed a windows answer).  Creating clear and concise questions is a skill that we all (including me) improve when receiving occasional tips.

Answer (score 2):

Yup - get TCPView from SysInternals, find the application and the connection, and close it. Failing that, restarting the application, unless the specific app has a way of doing this. Most apps won't.

Answer (score 0):

If the application is running under unix,

```
Kill -9 <pid>
```

will forcefully kill a process releasing all it's resources. The

```
<pid>
```

can be found by doing a

```
ps aex
```

at the command line.

Comment: This is on Windows.